# index.html not generated using maven-site-plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, indexing, pom.xml, maven-site-plugin

I am trying to generate a page for the reports of the project I am working on. It seems that I can't have the index.html page created.
In my pom file the maven-site-plugin is configured that way:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
</plugin>
```

I have my site.xml configured that way:

```
<project name="${project.name} site" combine.self="override">
    <bannerLeft>
        <name>${project.name}</name>
    </bannerLeft>
    <body>
        <menu name="Information">
            <item name="About" href="index.html"/>
            <item name="Project Information" href="project-info.html"/>
            <item name="Reports" href="project-reports.html"/>
    </body>
    <skin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.skins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-fluido-skin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </skin>
</project>
```

When I test this with `mvn clean site:site site:deploy` it generates the report pages with the correct left banner but there is no index.html page created.

Any clue how can I have that generated ?